# Multiple std::condition_variable notification to running thread using notify_one()

Tags: multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I'm trying to send multiple notifications to a running thread from another thread (main thread) using std::condition_variable. Sending it once works however doing it the second or multiple times doesn't seem to work. This is what I did (without unnecessary details of the actual events):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>

bool keep_running=true;
bool condition_reached=false;
std::mutex cond_mtx;
std::condition_variable cond;

void thread_waiting_to_be_notified(){
    while(keep_running){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cond_mtx);
        cond.wait(lk,[]()->bool{return condition_reached;});
        std::cout << "got notitication" << std::endl;
        condition_reached=false;
   }
}

void some_event(){
/*some event happens here*/
}

void another_event(){
/*another event happens here*/
}

int main(){
    std::thread thr(thread_waiting_to_be_notified);

    some_event();//first event
    std::cout << "some event happened" << std::endl;
    condition_reached=true;
    cond.notify_one();

    another_event();//second event
    std::cout << "another event happened" << std::endl; 
    condition_reached=true;
    cond.notify_one();
    keep_running=false;
    thr.join();

     return 0;
}
```

---

and the output I got

```
some event happened
another event happened
got notitication
```

However, I'd expect

```
some event happened
another event happened
got notitication
got notitication
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can clean up your code to make it readable..

Comment: You need a queue of events or an atomic counter. A condition variable does not remember how many times it has been notified. If the thread did not wake up between the events and reset the condition variable, then the second notification will have no effect.

Comment: Basically, instead of `bool condition_reached;` you need an `atomic<int> condition_counter;`

Comment: @IlyaPopov thanks...just checked...it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting `lk.unlock();` after

```
condition_reached=false;
```

Comment: Just noticed something interesting. If the function another_event() takes longer than 1 ns (nano sec) to process  then I get the expected result...even without lk.unlock()...I tested this with a small sleep on another_event() function using   std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ns); However the actual function takes much shorter than ....so I would still say its unpredictable behavior